# RecordMetric vs RecordResponseTimeMetric in new relic

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

I'm using .NET agent custom metrics for asp.net mvc application. I'm referring [this api](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/the-net-agent-api)

I'm not clear between RecordMetric and RecordResponseTimeMetric

What are basic differences between these two functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RecordMetric(System.String,System.Single)

Records a metric value for the given name. Supports all application types via custom dashboards.

RecordResponseTimeMetric(System.String,System.Int64)

Records a response time in milliseconds for the given metric name. Supports all application types via custom dashboards.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/the-net-agent-api

Comment: Okay...In RecordResponseTimeMetric, it will be record response time of particular line of code. But I'm still not clear in RecordMetric. What will RecordMetric be recorded? What will those terms or item be recorded?